# Opinion on football or cricket

Tags: word-usage, sentence-usage

So my friend asked me to what do you want your son to join in future football or cricket.

I replied there is enough people contributing their interests in cricket so football would be good.

Is that the correct way of reply.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

I would change your sentence a little bit. Instead of "contributing their interests in," people would say "are interested in."

> There are enough people interested in cricket, so football would be good / better.